# Storing timezoned HH:MM in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

My application needs to send a daily email to users at a time of their choosing, the timezone is also defined by the user itself.

What's the best way to store HH:MM + timezone? And how can I effectively query this, knowing that my server is in a specific timezone?

My current table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "reminder" (
    "id"            SERIAL          UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    "user"          INT             NOT NULL REFERENCES "user"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    "scheduled_at   TIMESTAMPTZ     NOT NULL,
    "created_at"    TIMESTAMPTZ     NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

I'm not sure if `TIMESTAMPTZ` is the most effective way to do this, since it stores the entire timestamp, and not just `HH:MM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a **`time`** and the **time zone name** as **text**.
**Not** `timetz`, which is broken and discouraged, and **not** just a time offset, which would break with daylight saving time (DST) and other time zone oddities.

I suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE reminder (
  id           int          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, user_id      int          NOT NULL REFERENCES "user"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
, scheduled_at time         NOT NULL
, tz           text         NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UTC'
, created_at   timestamptz  NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

To generate correct timestamps for "today" (as defined by your current `TimeZone` setting):

```
SELECT *
     , (CURRENT_DATE + scheduled_at) AT TIME ZONE tz AS tstz
     , (CURRENT_DATE + scheduled_at) AT TIME ZONE tz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_ts
FROM   reminder;
```

The resulting `tstz` may be on a different "day" for the receiver.
`utc_ts` is the according timestamp in the UTC time zone.

This related answer on SO fits precisely and has ample explanation:

- [Accounting for DST in Postgres, when selecting scheduled items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243029/939860)

Aside: I wouldn't use the [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) "user" as identifier.

Comment: That looks great, trying it out now! Also thanks for the tip on `user` and using `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` instead of `SERIAL`. I had to look it up, but seems that `SERIAL` is discouraged.

Comment: Can you share links to how timetz is broken and/or discouraged?

Comment: @JesusGalvan: The full quote from the manual is in the linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243029/939860. Basically, DST breaks the concept of `timetz`. While you don't know the exact date, `timetz` is ambiguous.